# How to reload the data from UI picker view and close the Picker view with transition

Tags: ios, swift

```
class MainVC: UIViewController {

    var datasourceForUsers :UserPicker!
    var userPicker :UIPickerView!
    var toolBar: UIToolbar!
    override func viewDidLoad() {

 super.viewDidLoad()

        userPicker = UIPickerView()
        toolBar = UIToolbar()
        datasourceForUsers = UserPicker()
 }

    @IBAction func onMoreTapped(){

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("ToggleSideMenu"), object: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func showRegisteredUsers(_ sender: Any) {

        createUserPicker()
        configureToolBar(toolBar)
    }


    func createUserPicker() {

        userPicker.dataSource = datasourceForUsers
        userPicker.delegate = datasourceForUsers
        //Customizations
        userPicker.backgroundColor = .black
        userPicker.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 300, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 300)
        self.view.addSubview(userPicker)
    }

    func configureToolBar(_ toolBar:UIToolbar  ){

        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        toolBar.barTintColor = .black
        toolBar.tintColor = .white

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(MainVC.dismissKeyboard))
        toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        toolBar.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 300, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 50)
        self.view.addSubview(toolBar)


    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        userPicker.reloadAllComponents()
        toolBar.reloadInputViews()
    }


    @objc func cancelDatePicker(){
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        }

        @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
           self.resignFirstResponder()

        }
 }
```

I used above code to show some data on `UIPickerView` .It works fine.But When I change the datasource(Add new Data) where the data  is stored it does not reflect  on the UI picker.In order to do that I have to run the application again.Second thing is I couldn't close the UI picker with transition.

Comment: Kindly rephrase your question, I am not able to understand the second line of your explanation 
"But, when I come from another view after changing the array where the data is stored for UIPickerView"

Comment: @RevanthKausikan I Edit the question.thanx

Comment: @arunm619, can you have a look into this?